# How do I make a `Pipe` or `TTY` with a custom callback in Julia?

Tags: julia

I'd like to fancy up my embedding of Julia in a MATLAB mex function by hooking up Julia's `STDIN`, `STDOUT`, and `STDERR` to the MATLAB terminal. The documentation for `redirect_std[in|out|err]` says that the stream that I pass in as the argument needs to be a `TTY` or a `Pipe` (or a `TcpSocket`, which wouldn't seem to apply).

I know how I will define the right callbacks for each stream (basically, wrappers around calls to MATLAB's `input` and `fprintf`), but I'm not sure how to construct the required stream.

Comment: if you're using julia-v0.4, use `TCPSocket` instead of `TcpSocket `. e.g. `a = TCPSocket()`.

Answer (score 2):

Pipe was renamed PipeEndpoint in https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/12739, but the corresponding documentation was not updated and PipeEndpoint is now considered internal. Even so, creating the pipe up front is still doable:

```
pipe = Pipe()
Base.link_pipe(pipe)
redirect_stdout(pipe.in)
@async while !eof(pipe)
    data = readavailable(pipe)
    # Pass data to whatever function handles display here
end
```

Furthermore, the no-argument version of these functions already create a pipe object, so the recommended way to do this would be:

```
(rd,wr) = redirect_stdout()
@async while !eof(rd)
    data = readavailable(rd)
    # Pass data to whatever function handles display here
end
```

Nevertheless, all of this is less clear than it could be, so I have created a pull request to clean up this API: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/18253. Once that pull request is merged, the `link_pipe` call will become unnecessary and `pipe` can be passed directly into `redirect_stdout`. Further, the return value from the no-argument version will become a regular `Pipe`.